# Automatically deleting archive on server in Django when client side download completes

Tags: python, django, download

In my server side code in Django, i download a set of files on the server and create an archive which is then sent to the client side for download.
Is there a way i can automatically delete this archive once the download on the client side is complete or aborted ?

Thank You

Comment: How do you send the file to client for download? Do you provide a link and webserver handles the download, or do you send it as django HttpResponse?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I usually return an archived file to user with HttpResponse and set the content type to "attachment". This way the download starts automatically and I don't have to save the archived file. Is this approach helps you or not?